# Does any function on $L^{1}_{loc}$ define a (tempered) distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

where the action is taken by integration ?

for example, $f=e^{-x}$ is in $L^p$ thus in $L^1$ thus in $L^{1}_{loc}$ and defines a tempered distribution. But what about $g=e^x$ ? Is it true that $g \in L^{1}_{loc}$ since $g$ is continuous and any continuous function is in $L^{1}_{loc}$ ? Then does $g$ define a (tempered) distribution ?

Comment: (no) yes${}{}$.

Comment: If $f\in L_{loc}^1$ is non-negative then it is a tempered distribution iff $\int_{-T}^T f(t)dt$ has at most polynomial growth. Also $(\sin(e^{e^x}))'$ is a tempered distribution even if it has much faster growth. If $h$ decreases faster than any inverse of polynomials then $h \ast \phi$ is a Schwartz function.

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is not in $L^1(\Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g(x)= e^x$ does not define a tempered distribution. Take $1\geq\psi\geq 0$ to be a smooth function with support in $(-2;2)$ and $\psi=1$ on $(-1,1)$, then $\phi(x) = e^{-\vert x \vert/2} (1-\psi(x))\in \mathcal{S}$. However,
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \phi(x) g(x) dx  \geq  \int_2^\infty e^{x/2} dx = \infty $$ 
Thus, $g$ does not define a tempered distribution. However, it does define a distribution (i.e. continuous linear function on the test functions) as it is locally integrable.

Comment: $e^{-x/2} \in S$ ????

Comment: @reuns Gosh, sorry for that... Corrected it.